# Add Padding Around All Webpage Contents

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage with an embedded javascript web app and the styling on that has messed up the padding on my web page. I would like to add padding around all the contents of the page so they are not completely pressed against the edge but nothing I seem to be doing is working. First i tried encompassing all the contents in the body with a div and adding CSS padding to that div but nothing. Then I tried adding padding to the body in the CSS file but nothing. Finally I tried `*{ padding: 10, 10, 10, 10 px; }` but still nothing. Any idea on how to add padding around all the contents of a webpage?

Answer (score 3):

`10` is an invalid value for `padding`. You're probably looking for `px` or `%`. Also, adding `padding` to `*` will add `padding` to **every single element on the page**, not just around the "edge" of the page.

```
body{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to that too if you notice a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Aibrean That's OT, but yes. [Here's a good article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) on that.

Answer (score 3):

Simple-

```
*{
   padding:5% /* or whatever */
}
```

Note- this is far from ideal. Better to use a full reset and amend accordingly. [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is fairly easy to decipher

Your syntax is wrong too, its `*{padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}`, no commas

**AMEND FOR APPARENT OP USE** -

```
body{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what the OP is looking for. I can understand the confusion but he wants padding on the `body` only.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution because every object (such as buttons and text) received padding and that really messed things up.

Comment: Hence "far from ideal..." and amendment point.